# Amount should not be less than 0 in grid using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

When I go to Insert first record into the `gridview`. What I want is, My `Amount` column should not be `0` or less than that.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
function checkAgrmVal() {
        for (var i = 0; i < GridPayInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
            var AgrmntAmt = GridPayInfo.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value;
            alert(AgrmntAmt);
            if (AgrmntAmt <= "0") {
                alert('Agreement amount cannot be 0 or less than 0');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't works when I go to add the first row, but it does work when I go to add the second row.

Comment: did you try and start with i=1 ?

Comment: @jogoe: Nope, I didn't tried with that. can u help me with your logic ?

Comment: @jogoe: I tried with `i=1` still for the first row it goes outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get table rows use `GridPayInfo.rows[i].cells[5]` not `Rows` and
  `Cells`
- To get Cell content use `innerText`, `textContent` to get text or `innerHTML` to get HTML not `.Value`.
- `.Value` should be `.value` that works with input and textarea.

So Your example should work see below code:

```js
function checkAgrmVal() {
var GridPayInfo = document.getElementById("tbl");
        for (var i = 0; i < GridPayInfo.rows.length; i++) {
            var AgrmntAmt = GridPayInfo.rows[i].cells[5].innerText;
            if (AgrmntAmt <= "0") {
                alert('Agreement amount cannot be 0 or less than 0 found in row: '+ (+i+1));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<table id='tbl'>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>-1</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>-4</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick='checkAgrmVal()'>check</button>
```

Comment: let me try and check.

Comment: Getting error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required` at line `i < GridPayInfo.rows.length`

Comment: be sure your GridPayInfo variable refers to table element id correctly

Comment: yes, resolved that, Now getting error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'rows[...].cells.5.innerText' is null or not an object`

Comment: rows[...].cells.5 is not valid ===> rows[...].cells[5]

Comment: I added like this, `var AgrmntAmt = GridPayInfo.rows[i].cells[5].innerText;` but the same error occured

Comment: so you have 6 columns or ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127280/discussion-between-nad-and-mamdouh-freelancer).